# No destruye la sesión en PHP $_SESSION unset

Tags: php, session

Estoy **logueado en una página del administrador** para poder modificar una serie de atributos de unas reservas, y cuando pulso sobre **SALIR**, debo destruir la sesión y que me redirija a la página "**reservar.php**".

De acuerdo, pulso **SALIR**, se sale de la página "**menu_administrador.php**" y me redirige a "**reservar.php**", el problema viene que si en el navegador pongo de nuevo "menu_administrador.php" me sigue cargando el administrador que tenía, es decir, **no borra la sesión.**

**Código:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }else{
        header("Location: iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</a></p>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "administrador".
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Resto del código ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como dices, **antes** de hacer el unset te **redirije** a la página **reservar.php** la cual no es donde tienes actualmente el código unset. Por tanto esa parte del código no se está ejecutando.

```
//Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
   //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "administrador".
   unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
}
```

Éste código citado que tenías en **menu_administrador.php** debes pasarlo al fichero **reservar.php**, con su correspondiente **session_start()** al inicio del fichero.

Es de buena práctica al trabajar con sesiones usar el método **session_destroy()** para destruir todos los datos registrados a la sesión al implementar tu "Salir/Logout". Para ello tu código de **reservar.php** quedaría así:

```
session_start();
//Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "administrador".
    session_destroy();
}
```

También está la posibilidad de liberar todas las variables de la sesión con:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Que sería equivalente a:

```
session_unset();
```

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo quedaría el código con el método session_destroy()?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para tu aclaración.